# Why the notation grad(f) for the gradient in Riemannian geometry?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The most used notations for the gradient of a function $f$ in Riemannian geometry are, in my experience: $\nabla f$ and $\mathrm{grad} f$. Why does the second exist? When was it introduced? Why don't we just stick with $\nabla f$?

Comment: afaik it's mostly just to jolt you out of thinking of it as a 'vector' whose entries are just $\partial f/\partial x_i$ and get you to respect its true and more general definition in Riemannian geometry (as e.g. $(df)^{\sharp}$ iirc)

Comment: This could also be to avoid confusion with the (Levi-Civita) connection, usually written as $\nabla$.

Comment: They are two different things, $\nabla f$ is a $1$-form (so pointwise is a covector), instead $\mathrm{grad}f$ is a vector field (so pointwise is a vector).
The relation between the two is that $\nabla_X f = \langle \mathrm{grad} f, X\rangle$ where $\langle, \rangle$ is the Riemmanian metric and $X$ is a vector field.